Does the "exception clause" in Matthew 5 and Matthew 19 permit divorce or explain culpability for adultery?
Nearly all the interpretations I've seen of the "exception clause" treat it as expressing a situation where divorce could be allowed, but I've heard another interpretation that instead attaches it to the following clause, concerning the commission of adultery (i.e. a man cannot cause his wife to commit adultery [by divorcing her, thereby forcing her to remarry] if she is already an adulteress).
Its placement in English (and in Greek) between the clauses seems to let it work either way, muddying the issue, and the reading one way or the other would either undercut a major argument of the "pro-divorce" position, strengthening the "anti-divorce" position, or vice versa, especially since these, along with I Cor. 7:15 are the only passages that seem to permit divorce, and the latter is clearly only for a "mixed" marriage between a believer and unbeliever.
So I'm wondering, is there anything in the structure of the Greek grammar that indicates which verb the exception should apply to?
Matthew 5:32 (KJV)

but I say unto you, That whosoever shall put away his wife, saving for the cause of fornication, causeth her to commit adultery: and whosoever shall marry her that is divorced committeth adultery.

Matthew 19:9 (KJV)

And I say unto you, Whosoever shall put away his wife, except it be for fornication, and shall marry another, committeth adultery: and whoso marrieth her which is put away doth commit adultery.

See Matthew 5:32 and Matthew 19:9 for the variant Greek manuscript readings.
Related: This question, the answers of which discuss some of the various interpretations and contexts surrounding these and other passages, but doesn't address this particular question.

The proper translation is 'causes adultery to her'. Which is perfectly clear and agrees with Paul 'the woman that hath a husband is bound by the law to her husband as long as her husband liveth' (whether said husband likes it or not).

Note that this scripture does not read " except for the cause of adultery".  Various translations read "for fornication" or "for sexual immorality" but it is never translated as "for adultery".  People tend to put all of these in one category but you have to be careful with that.  A married person can commit adultery but cannot commit fornication.

Matthew 5:32 (KJV)

but I say unto you, That whosoever shall put away his wife, saving for the cause of fornication, causeth her to commit adultery: and whosoever shall marry her that is divorced committeth adultery.

Fornication involves two unmarried persons, while adultery involves at least one married person. According to Jesus:

If a man finds his wife was not a virgin at the time of their marriage, implying she engaged in sexual immorality(NIV version) without his prior knowledge, he has the right to divorced her. This is the only exception for divorce that God acknowledge.
Aside from this exception, they remain a married couple even if the man divorces his wife in God's judgment.
Therefore if the divorced wife remarries for her own survival or becomes a prostitute, the man is responsible for causing her to commit adultery.
Furthermore, a man who marries her also commit adultery, as in God's sight, she is still a married woman.


Here is my very (overly) literal translation of these texts:

Matt 5:32 - But I say to you that everyone divorcing his wife, except
on account of sexual immorality, causes her to commit adultery.  And
whoever shall marry the divorcee commits adultery
Matt 19:9 - But I say to you that whoever shall divorce his wife
except for sexual immorality, and marries another, commits adultery.

Note that the exception case is quite clear.  The case of Matt 5:32 is quite interesting.  Note that Jesus is saying that the act of divorcing a wife causes her to commit adultery - this was because in the Roman-Jewish world of the 1st century, it was rare and very difficult for a woman to be able to live a single life - almost all had to find a husband or face an invidious choice - get married or enter the life of prostitution.
It was for these reasons that the early church set up the widows fund as recorded in Acts 6 to care for widows.
Paul reinforces this point in 1 Cor 7 - if a couple separates, then no adultery is committed.  Indeed, he encourages couples to either separate or be reconciled.

But is the "causing her to commit adultery" the part excepted? I.e. a divorcing husband makes his (ex-)wife to become an adulteress (because she essentially must remarry), unless by sexual immorality she already is one, so then he's not culpable for forcing her into an adulterous situation? (...not to say he's not culpable for other wrongs related to the situation, but just for that point in particular.)

@JedSchaaf - there is the ,matter of which is innocent part - if the husband is unfaithful, then the divorced wife is free to remarry.  However, if the wife is unfaithful, then divorcing her makes her continue to commit adultery by essentially forcing her to remarry.  But this is getting pedantic.  (Recall that a woman could not divorce her husband, only a man could divorce his wife.)

Mark 10:12 explicitly mentions a woman who divorces her husband. And the Samaritan woman had had 5 husbands (apparently she had divorced at least some of them to get to that many).

@JedSchaaf - actually, the word used is simply "separate" not divorced.  Women could not divorce their husbands.  Some simply left the home and took up with another man.

If a couple separates, then no adultery is committed. No Greek text exists which expresses such a sentiment. 'Bound by the law to her husband as long as her husband liveth' is the apostolic wording.

@NigelJ - agreed - in 1 Cor 7 we have permission to separate

I Cor. 7 doesn't indicate that remarriage (after an unbelieving spouse departs from a believing spouse) won't be adultery.


1  @Dottard the NABRE (which is a Catholic bible and perhaps biased against divorce) translates the key term as "unlawful" basically meaning a type of incest.  Is there a basis for this in terms of the Greek? A footnote says: "the unlawfulness that Matthew gives as a reason why a marriage must be broken refers to a situation peculiar to his community: the violation of Mosaic law forbidding marriage between persons of certain blood and/or legal relationship (Lv 18:6–18). Marriages of that sort were regarded as incest (porneia)"


@DanFefferman - well, "porneia" as defined by BDAG is 'unlawful sex" which includes, adultery, premarital sex, bestiality, incest, homosexuality, pedophilia, etc, etc.  Now, whether this unlawfulness is according to Torah law or Roman law is another question and sometimes subtle because what was lawful and what was acceptable in society are not the same.

You ask a good question. But it's a difficult one to answer, since, at the end of the day, it boils down to how one word is used.  In the Greek we have these words:

ἐγὼ δὲ λέγω ὑμῖν ὅτι πᾶς ὁ ἀπολύων τὴν γυναῖκα αὐτοῦ
παρεκτὸς λόγου πορνείας ποιεῖ αὐτὴν μοιχευθῆναι· καὶ ὃς
ἐὰν ἀπολελυμένην γαμήσῃ, μοιχᾶται.

My translation:

but I’m telling you that everyone who divorces his wife when she
hasn’t committed a sin of sexual immorality causes her to appear as if
she were an adulteress.  And the man who marries the divorced woman
commits adultery.

The one word that gives us pause is the word, "ⲙⲟⲓⲭⲉⲩⲑⲏⲛⲁⲓ". It's a passive infinitive.  We would expect an active infinitive if the verse had the concept of actively committing adultery.
There are times that passive verbs take on active meaning. For example, consider the many times ⲉⲫⲏ pops up in the NT. It's a passive form. But it's translated actively. This could be one of those examples. The CSB takes it that way:

“But I tell you, everyone who divorces his wife, except in a case of
sexual immorality, causes her to commit adultery. And whoever marries
a divorced woman commits adultery.” (Matthew 5:32 CSB17)

But could be taken in a different sense.  John Brug ponders the possibility in his exegetical brief A puzzling verb form:

A Puzzling Verb Form
Students of the New Testament have long been puzzled by a strange
passive verb in Matthew 5:32, μοιχευθῆναι . The correct
interpretation of this verb is very important because of its
significance in establishing the scriptural teaching concerning
divorce. Is the passive of this verb "to commit adultery" to be
translated actively when used of a woman? The husband who divorces the
woman "causes her to commit adultery." The use of the passive form
when a woman commits an act of adultery does occur in Scripture (see
Lv 20:10 in the Septuagint). But it does not seem to be in harmony
with the context of Matthew 5 and with the rest of Scripture to
translate this passage in a way which suggests that a man who unjustly
divorces his wife "makes her commit adultery" if she remarries. Some
commentaries and translations render this verb as a true passive, with
an expression like "he causes her to be stigmatized as an adulteress."
Some have argued, however, that this is not the normal force of the
passive of this verb when applied to the actions of a woman (even
though Kittel and Liddell and Scott indicate that the verb does have
the meaning to "violate" or "debauch"—both of which include the idea
of how the woman is viewed by others).
Some light may be shed on this problem by another strange verb which
occurs in Deuteronomy 24:4, a hutqattel of the verb ) טמא (be
unclean). There are only four hutqattel forms in the Old Testament.
They all have a passive subject and undersubject. The hutqattel
conjugation also called Hothpa'al (Gesenius Kautzach  Cowley, 54h),
also has a declarative force. Thus, Deuteronomy 24:4 should be
translated, "she had been made to declare herself to be unclean" by
her first husband's act of divorcing her. This uncleanness did not
result from an act of immorality by the woman nor from her marriage to
a second husband, but from the declaration that she had been forced to
make by her first husband when he divorced her. The woman is not
forbidden to remarry after her first or second marriage. She is only
forbidden to remarry her first husband who had caused her to declare
herself to be unclean by his divorce action against her. The
prohibition of Deuteronomy 24 is really directed against her first
husband, not against the woman.
A fuller study of the hutqattel and its implications in Deuteronomy 24
may be found in Hebrew Studies, 1991, pp 8 17.
A correct understanding of Deuteronomy 24:4 may help solve the problem
of Matthew 5:32. The puzzling passive in Matthew may be an attempt to
express a grammatical and moral situation which is very like that in
Deuteronomy 24. A selfish husband is forcing a wife to declare herself
unclean. Greek had no verbal form exactly parallel to the hutqattel of
Hebrew, but the writer of the Gospel is trying to express a similar
thought with the closest form which he had available to him.
The interpretation of the puzzling verb in Deuteronomy 24 may shed
some light on the puzzling verb in Matthew 5. The force of the
hutqattel may be one more bit of grammatical information to be
considered by advocates of translating Matthew 5:32, her husband
"causes her to be looked upon as an adulteress and whoever marries her
is looked upon as an adulterer." This would have approximately the
same force as the hutqattel in Deuteronomy 24.

To summarize, the rare use of the aorist passive of this word (ⲙⲟⲓⲭⲉⲩⲑⲏⲛⲁⲓ) can mean, "to make one appear to be" or " to make one be treated as." The context then is that the wife did not commit adultery. But, by divorcing her, the husband creates an environment that she is considered to be an adulteress when she is not.
We note the update in the NIV translation.  In the NIV 84, we read:

“But I tell you that anyone who divorces his wife, except for marital
unfaithfulness, causes her to become an adulteress, and anyone who
marries the divorced woman commits adultery.” (Matthew 5:32 NIV-GK)

However, in the NIV update, we read:

“But I tell you that anyone who divorces his wife, except for sexual
immorality, makes her the victim of adultery, and anyone who marries a
divorced woman commits adultery.” (Matthew 5:32 NIV11-GKE)

The NIV update contains some changes I would not approve of. But here is one that I wholeheartedly approve.
The key issue remains this: how much weight are we going to put on one verb form?  I find John Brug's argument compelling. And I'm thankful that the NIV went back, did some more research, and arrived at their updated translation here.
